# Can I create the javascript function run before bodyrender and after bodyrender In MVC3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have  @RenderBody() method to render In layoutpage and I want to know when it start and when it download finish by javascript. How can I do because I want my webpage have a overlay when It downloading content. I can do in ajax but I dont know how to do it in MVC @RenderBody().

Comment: What is the aim of this actions? It seems to me that you should not do this to achieve you aim

Comment: and how can I achieve ? i don't know how to create some screen to overlay my web page when rendering. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Ususally some screen is necessary when you show page and download some specific data by ajax request.

When you render content in layout with `RenderBody()` it renders full page (layout and content) on server return it to `Response.OutputStream` as whole unit.

So you don't need to screen anything.